# difficulty with prob.3 on project euler (in c++)

Tags: c++

so, I've been trying to solve this problem for a few hours now. 
shortly I arrived to a solution that logically -  should work and is working, but only for numbers no bigger than 10^7. I guess I could just const the specific number they asked for (600851475143) but I would really love to know - why my code isn't working with big numbers?

this is my code for the solution :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
//enter any number and its largest prime factor will be detected.
int main()
{
    long largest(1),num(0);
    bool primecheck;
    cout<<"enter the desired number :"<<endl;
    cin>>num;
    if (num%2==0)
        largest=2;
    cout<<"the relevant factors are: ";
    for (int i=3;i<=int((sqrt(num))/2);i+=2)
        {
            primecheck=true;
            for(int j=2;j<i;j++)
                {
                    if(i%j==0)
                        primecheck=false;
                }
            if(primecheck)
                if(num%i==0)
                {
                    largest=i;
                    cout<< largest<<"\t";
                }
        }
    cout<<endl<< "the largest prime factor of the number you have entered is: " <<largest;
    return 0;
}
```

thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Please refrain asking question about online code judge engines here. It's very  unlikely that anyone could tell you where you failed from their testcases, as these aren't disclosed usually. Even if what you tested was running at your local environment, you may have missed to test some edge cases which are applied in the online challenge. Be creative and try to find them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Problem with your code-**

Use **long long int** as data type instead of **long int** since C++ recognizes **long int** as having same range as **int**.

**If you want to refer my concise solution in C/C++ -**

*For C++ just change the header file to iostream.

```
#include <cstdio>
#define MAX 775147
#define NUM 600851475143

int main()
{
  long long n = NUM;
  int max = 3;
  for(int i = 3; i <= MAX; i+=2)
  {
    if(n%i == 0)
      max = i;
    while(n%i == 0)
    {
      n /= i; 
    }
  }
  printf("%d\n", max);
  return 0;  
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. There's just no guarantee a char is bigger than a short or a short is bigger than an int or an int is bigger ... Regarding C/C++, don't do that unless you are absolutely clueless: Do you mean C or C++, C and C++, C mixed with C++ or what? BTW: Your code is neither valid C nor C++.

Comment: This code is in C. I have mentioned that if you want to run that in C++ use iostream header file instead of cstdio.

Comment: thanks a lot! solved the issue indeed :) I never encountered the use of long long determination before...

Comment: no problem bro. And stop solving project euler, and move to spoj. If you have any qeuries regarding competitive programming message me.

Comment: <cstdio> is not a C header, nor does that header in C++ have to introduce its contents into the global namespace.

Comment: yeah I realised that later, I had written that code long ago in C++ only. cstdio is equivalent to stdio.h in C for C++.

Comment: looks interesting, I'll give it a shot. and thanks man, sure thing! keep on rocking!